# Setup IP camera in Windows 10 as native webcam device (D-Link DCS-8325LH) (ONVIF Profile S)

Tags: windows, windows-10, webcam, ip-camera

### Setup

- Windows 10 Version 2004 (OS Build 19041.388)

  - via VirtualBox 6.1.10
  - Network-Adapter is in Bridge mode
  - also tested with Version 2004 (OS Build 20170.1000) (Dev Channel)
- DCS-8325LH camera (Firmware 1.01.04)

### Goal

I want to use the network/IP camera as a native camera device in Windows so that a browser for example recognizes the IP camera like a regular connected webcam after setup.

### Assumption

I'm not familiar with Windows but from what i understand, ONVIF is the only way to add a network camera so that it behaves like a native windows camera device? I want to support a bigger camera setup (like 10 cameras for example where every camera is the same make and model).

### Steps to reproduce

1. Connect webcam to WiFi via "mydlink" app via smartphone
2. In Windows, go to Settings -> Bluetooth & other devices -> Add Bluetooth or other device
3. Select "Everything else"
4. Wait for DCS-8325LH to appear
5. Click "DCS-8325LH"

[image: Camera discovered by Windows 10]

### Expected result

Webcam gets installed or prompts for credentials (the webcam has a pin-code on the bottom)

### Actual result

It only flashes "Connecting" very shortly but nothing happens

### Debug information

#### Wireshark

I sniffed the communcation, i can see SOAP request and responses successfully be exchanged.
Some requests are denied by the webcam, which i believe is the issue.

The [full package capture is available as a .pcapng file download](https://github.com/BreiteSeite/BreiteSeite.github.io/raw/master/assets/d-link-onvif-capture.pcapng).

[image: wireshark capture showing 200 and 403 responses]

Any idea how to make this work is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer lies in Microsofts Blog post "[Connecting Network Cameras to Windows 10 Devices](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/10/10/connecting-network-cameras-to-windows-10-devices/)":

> If the ability to **pair to authenticated cameras with the Settings page** is important for your use case, please let us know via the Windows Developer Feedback.

Unfortunately, the link to the Windows Developer Feedback is dead.

So the issues likely is that the cameras require authentication which windows doesn't support at this point. I tried 3 cameras in total:

- Hikvision DS-2CD2045FWD-I
- Reolink RLC-410-5MP
- D-Link DCS-8325LH

None of them seem to support unauthenticated ONVIF, so they can not be used with the Windows 10 versions mentioned in the question out of the box.